# Shared Preferences Not working over multiple contexts

Tags: java, android, android-context

Put into shared preferences code:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Bookmarks.this).edit()
    .putString("togoto", link).apply();
String togoto = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Bookmarks.this)
    .getString("togoto", "no");
Toast.makeText(Bookmarks.this, "Will go to "+togoto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_proxy_browser);

Intent myIntent = new Intent(Bookmarks.this, ProxyBrowserActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Get from shared prferences (In other context):

```
String togoto = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ProxyBrowserActivity.this).getString("togoto", "nogo");
Toast.makeText(ProxyBrowserActivity.this, "1 Going to "+togoto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
if (togoto != "no") {
    Toast.makeText(ProxyBrowserActivity.this, "Going to "+togoto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ProxyBrowserActivity.this)
        .edit().putString("togoto", "no").apply();
} else {
    // no shared preferences
}
```

This does not appear to work and `togoto` returns no on the other context. How do I allow it to work over multiple contexts?

Comment: What you have should work fine - there are probably some missing details that cause the issue not included in the question. Where is the code in the second activity located? Inside `onCreate`? Calling `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` is fine with different contexts, internally it just calls `context.getSharedPreferences(name,key)` with name of `context.getPackageName() + "_preferences"` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
getSharedPreferences(KEY, MODE_PRIVATE) rather than 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferenceManager.
```

Your code is fine when you replace this.

Comment: Actually, your code is good. please check other part if something modifies again.

Comment: Still working on it

Answer (score 0):

If u create a default SharedPreference, it' name is `context.getPackageName() + "_preferences"`. And `getDefaultSharedPreferences` get that. When u set a name like "MyApp_preferences", `getDefaultSharedPreferences` will find nothing. Use `getSharedPreferences`.